# How to use the exam class in another language

Tags: exam

Can we use the `exam` document class and all its packages in another language?

For example, how can we have the info about the exam translated in another languge?

Comment: Could you please add a MWE?

Comment: [ctan’s topic list for “exam”](http://www.ctan.org/topic/exam) shows several you might try (for example, `esami` is iirc in italian); beyond that, i reckon you would need actual work on the package itself.  try asking the author!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) with other languages, but you need to translate by yourself.

Its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) contains all commands which you need to redefine the labels. In the following (bad) example, some of these commands are used/listed:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{Left}{Center}{Right}
\runningheader{LeftM}{Middle, Page \thepage\ of \numpages}{RightM}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\pointpoints{exam-point}{exam-points}
\bonuspointpoints{exam-bonus-point}{exam-bonus-points}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion}\quad (\totalpoints)\hfill}

\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{The solution:}\enspace}

\begin{document}
\addpoints    
\begin{questions}
        \question[10]
        The question 1.
        \begin{solution}
        This is the answer to question 1.
        \end{solution}

        \question
        \begin{parts}
                \part[5] The question 2a.
                \part[5] The question 2b.
                \bonuspart[1] The question 2c.
        \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\newpage

% \chqword{Question:}
% \chpgword{Page:}
% \chpword{Points:}
% \chbpword{Bonus Points:}
% \chsword{Score:}
 \chtword{Total Points}
 \cvqword{Question-No.}
% \cvpgword{Page}
 \cvpword{Exam-Points}
 \cvbpword{Bonus Exam-Points}
% \cvsword{Score}
% \cvtword{Total:
\combinedgradetable

\end{document}
```